# Read only explicitly named columns and skip others with read.table

Tags: r, read.table

I know that I can use `colClasses` to set some column types to `NULL`, and then those will be skipped.

What I really want is to have the default column class to be `NULL`. Then I can simply specify the columns I need by name `colClasses(foo="numeric", bar="factor")` and get only what I asked for.

Is there any way to achieve this without too much work to construct an appropriate `colClasses` vector?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using `fread` from the package data.table.

```
data <- fread("filename.csv", 
          select = c("foo", "bar"), 
          colClasses = c(foo="numeric", bar="factor"))
```